# Go up one command instead of one line in IPython 5

Tags: ipython, prompt-toolkit

IPython 5 is a big release. One of its features is real multi-line editing with prompt_toolkit. The up arrow key now moves to the previous input line instead of the previous input command (block of lines).

This is awesome, but when my previous command spans many lines, and I need to reach the command before that, I find myself wishing I could go up one command at a time. Is there a way to do that? The shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> has the exact same behaviour as the up arrow key, so it does not provide a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my own Belgian Mac keyboard, <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> does the job. But I cannot tell whether this also works for other locales.

Answer (score 2):

The PageUp and PageDown keys do exactly what you want without any chorded hotkeys involved; they work on an entry-oriented basis, rather than the arrow keys' line oriented approach.

Comment: For me, these keys slide the terminal window itself.